# XSLT transform an element to an attribute and remove an element XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I've asked a question similar to this before, but I'm a little confused here.

I have an XML, and I want to transform some elements into attributes of their parent. I'm already doing this for one element, but I want to do it for another element. I thought it would be a case of copying the XSLT code and renaming the parts that needed to be changed, but it's not quite working as expected - it's removing the nodes from the element, but it's not changing them to an attribute, they're just disappearing.

I'm also trying to remove an element based on it's value compared to another element. This is also done in another element in my XSLT, but when I copy the code, I can't seem to get the same result. I want to remove the "task_info" element nested in "press_section" when the "task_seq_id" in "task_info" doesn't match the "sequence_id" in "press_section".

Lastly, I have also noticed that my XSLT is no longer removing the "dataroot" element from my XML.

I really can't see what I'm doing here in all honesty, so I would appreciate some help.

Thanks everyone!

Here is my input XML;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" generated="2015-01-16T10:32:47">
<order>
<ORDERPK>4</ORDERPK>
<job_id>S019191-1</job_id>
<site_code>DG</site_code>
<Replace>true</Replace>
<job_description>TEST</job_description>
<order_qty>2000</order_qty>
<depth>10</depth>
<width>8</width>
<cover_pagination>4</cover_pagination>
<text_pagination>12</text_pagination>
<delivery_commence_date>15/1/2014</delivery_commence_date>
<job_site>DG</job_site>
<managing_printer>DG</managing_printer>
<is_managing_printer>True</is_managing_printer>
</order>
<master_version>
<ORDER>3</ORDER>
<version_code>COMM</version_code>
<version_common>true</version_common>
<version_finished>false</version_finished>
<version_description>common</version_description>
<version_nett_qty>20000</version_nett_qty>
<version_special_qty>0</version_special_qty>
</master_version>
<master_version>
<ORDER>4</ORDER>
<version_code>COMM</version_code>
<version_common>true</version_common>
<version_finished>false</version_finished>
<version_description>common</version_description>
<version_nett_qty>2000</version_nett_qty>
</master_version>
<press_section>
<ORDER>3</ORDER>
<signature_id>001</signature_id>
<sequence_id>0</sequence_id>
<sequence_alpha>A</sequence_alpha>
<description>4pp Cover</description>
<pagination>4</pagination>
<trim_size>10 x 8</trim_size>
</press_section>
<press_section>
<ORDER>4</ORDER>
<signature_id>001</signature_id>
<sequence_id>0</sequence_id>
<sequence_alpha>A</sequence_alpha>
<description>4pp Cover</description>
<pagination>4</pagination>
<trim_size>10 x 8</trim_size>
</press_section>
<press_section>
<ORDER>4</ORDER>
<signature_id>001</signature_id>
<sequence_id>1</sequence_id>
<sequence_alpha>A</sequence_alpha>
<description>6pp Cover</description>
<pagination>6</pagination>
<trim_size>10 x8</trim_size>
</press_section>
<version>
<ORDER>3</ORDER>
<version_code>COMM</version_code>
</version>
<version>
<ORDER>4</ORDER>
<version_code>COMM</version_code>
</version>
<task_info_press_section>
<ORDER>3</ORDER>
<PRESS_x0020_SECTION>3</PRESS_x0020_SECTION>
<confirmed>true</confirmed>
<maintenance>false</maintenance>
<provisional>false</provisional>
<task_sub_job_id>S026500-1-001COMM</task_sub_job_id>
<task_seq_id>0</task_seq_id>
<task_description>4ppCover</task_description>
<task_qty_rqd>20000</task_qty_rqd>
<task_resource_id>2</task_resource_id>
</task_info_press_section>
<task_info_press_section>
<ORDER>4</ORDER>
<PRESS_x0020_SECTION>4</PRESS_x0020_SECTION>
<confirmed>-1</confirmed>
<maintenance>0</maintenance>
<provisional>0</provisional>
<task_sub_job_id>S019191-1-001COMM</task_sub_job_id>
<task_seq_id>0</task_seq_id>
<task_description>4pp Cover</task_description>
<task_qty_rqd>1500</task_qty_rqd>
<task_resource_id>1</task_resource_id>
</task_info_press_section>
<task_info_press_section>
<ORDER>4</ORDER>
<PRESS_x0020_SECTION>4</PRESS_x0020_SECTION>
<confirmed>-1</confirmed>
<maintenance>0</maintenance>
<provisional>0</provisional>
<task_sub_job_id>S019191-1-001COMM</task_sub_job_id>
<task_seq_id>1</task_seq_id>
<task_description>6pp Cover</task_description>
<task_qty_rqd>500</task_qty_rqd>
<task_resource_id>1</task_resource_id>
</task_info_press_section>
</dataroot>
```

Here is XSLT 1;

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">


   <xsl:template match="/">
     <orders xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tg="http://www.technique-group.com" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.technique-group.com/schemas TGScheduleImport_v1.4.xsd" tg:version="1.2">
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </orders>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- remove elements that don't match order -->
   <xsl:template match="master_version[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
   <xsl:template match="press_section[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
   <xsl:template match="version[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
   <xsl:template match="task_info_press_section[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
   <xsl:template match="task_info_post_press[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
   <xsl:template match="post_press_version[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>

   <!-- removed unwanted nodes from all elements -->
   <xsl:template match="ORDER"/>
   <xsl:template match="ORDERPK"/>
   <xsl:template match="PRESS_x0020_SECTION"/>
   <xsl:template match="POST_x0020_PRESS"/>


   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>


   <!-- create attributes in order element -->
   <xsl:template match="dataroot">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::*)]|order"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="job_id | site_code | replace | Replace"/>

   <xsl:template match="order">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::*)]|task_info_press_section"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="confirmed | maintenance | provisional"/>


   <!-- identity transform -->
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>


   <!-- nest specified element within matched element -->
   <xsl:template match="press_section">
    <press_section>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="../version"/>
    </press_section>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="version">
    <version>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="../task_info_press_section"/>
    </version>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="post_press_version">
    <post_press_version>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="../task_info_post_press"/>
    </post_press_version>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="task_info_press_section">
    <task_info_press_section confirmed="{confirmed}" maintenance="{maintenance}" provisional="{provisional}">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="../*[not(self::task_info_press_section)]"/>
    </task_info_press_section>
   </xsl:template>


   <!-- nest all elements within order and create attributes -->
   <xsl:template match="order">
    <order job_id="{job_id}" site_code="{site_code}" replace="{Replace}">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="../*[not(self::order) and not(self::version) and not(self::task_info_press_section) and not(self::task_info_post_press)]"/>
    </order>
   </xsl:template>


   <!-- rename elements to specified name -->
   <xsl:template match="task_info_press_section">
      <xsl:element name="task_info">
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="task_info_post_press">
      <xsl:element name="task_info">
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is XSLT 2;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:tg="http://www.technique-group.com"
    version="1.2">

<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="tg:{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.technique-group.com">
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is my output XML;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tg:orders xmlns:tg="http://www.technique-group.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.technique-group.com/schemas TGScheduleImport_v1.4.xsd" tg:version="1.2">
   <tg:dataroot generated="2015-01-16T10:32:47">
      <tg:order job_id="S019191-1" site_code="DG" replace="true">
         <tg:job_description>TEST</tg:job_description>
         <tg:order_qty>2000</tg:order_qty>
         <tg:depth>10</tg:depth>
         <tg:width>8</tg:width>
         <tg:cover_pagination>4</tg:cover_pagination>
         <tg:text_pagination>12</tg:text_pagination>
         <tg:delivery_commence_date>15/1/2014</tg:delivery_commence_date>
         <tg:job_site>DG</tg:job_site>
         <tg:managing_printer>DG</tg:managing_printer>
         <tg:is_managing_printer>True</tg:is_managing_printer>
         <tg:master_version>
            <tg:version_code>COMM</tg:version_code>
            <tg:version_common>true</tg:version_common>
            <tg:version_finished>false</tg:version_finished>
            <tg:version_description>common</tg:version_description>
            <tg:version_nett_qty>2000</tg:version_nett_qty>
         </tg:master_version>
         <tg:press_section>
            <tg:signature_id>001</tg:signature_id>
            <tg:sequence_id>0</tg:sequence_id>
            <tg:sequence_alpha>A</tg:sequence_alpha>
            <tg:description>4pp Cover</tg:description>
            <tg:pagination>4</tg:pagination>
            <tg:trim_size>10 x 8</tg:trim_size>
            <tg:version>
               <tg:version_code>COMM</tg:version_code>
               <tg:task_info>
                  <tg:task_sub_job_id>S019191-1-001COMM</tg:task_sub_job_id>
                  <tg:task_seq_id>0</tg:task_seq_id>
                  <tg:task_description>4pp Cover</tg:task_description>
                  <tg:task_qty_rqd>1500</tg:task_qty_rqd>
                  <tg:task_resource_id>1</tg:task_resource_id>
               </tg:task_info>
               <tg:task_info>
                  <tg:task_sub_job_id>S019191-1-001COMM</tg:task_sub_job_id>
                  <tg:task_seq_id>1</tg:task_seq_id>
                  <tg:task_description>6pp Cover</tg:task_description>
                  <tg:task_qty_rqd>500</tg:task_qty_rqd>
                  <tg:task_resource_id>1</tg:task_resource_id>
               </tg:task_info>
            </tg:version>
         </tg:press_section>
         <tg:press_section>
            <tg:signature_id>001</tg:signature_id>
            <tg:sequence_id>1</tg:sequence_id>
            <tg:sequence_alpha>A</tg:sequence_alpha>
            <tg:description>6pp Cover</tg:description>
            <tg:pagination>6</tg:pagination>
            <tg:trim_size>10 x8</tg:trim_size>
            <tg:version>
               <tg:version_code>COMM</tg:version_code>
               <tg:task_info>
                  <tg:task_sub_job_id>S019191-1-001COMM</tg:task_sub_job_id>
                  <tg:task_seq_id>0</tg:task_seq_id>
                  <tg:task_description>4pp Cover</tg:task_description>
                  <tg:task_qty_rqd>1500</tg:task_qty_rqd>
                  <tg:task_resource_id>1</tg:task_resource_id>
               </tg:task_info>
               <tg:task_info>
                  <tg:task_sub_job_id>S019191-1-001COMM</tg:task_sub_job_id>
                  <tg:task_seq_id>1</tg:task_seq_id>
                  <tg:task_description>6pp Cover</tg:task_description>
                  <tg:task_qty_rqd>500</tg:task_qty_rqd>
                  <tg:task_resource_id>1</tg:task_resource_id>
               </tg:task_info>
            </tg:version>
         </tg:press_section>
      </tg:order>
   </tg:dataroot>
</tg:orders>
```

Here is my desired output;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tg:orders xmlns:tg="http://www.technique-group.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.technique-group.com/schemas TGScheduleImport_v1.4.xsd" tg:version="1.2">
      <tg:order job_id="S019191-1" site_code="DG" replace="true">
         <tg:job_description>TEST</tg:job_description>
         <tg:order_qty>2000</tg:order_qty>
         <tg:depth>10</tg:depth>
         <tg:width>8</tg:width>
         <tg:cover_pagination>4</tg:cover_pagination>
         <tg:text_pagination>12</tg:text_pagination>
         <tg:delivery_commence_date>15/1/2014</tg:delivery_commence_date>
         <tg:job_site>DG</tg:job_site>
         <tg:managing_printer>DG</tg:managing_printer>
         <tg:is_managing_printer>True</tg:is_managing_printer>
         <tg:master_version>
            <tg:version_code>COMM</tg:version_code>
            <tg:version_common>true</tg:version_common>
            <tg:version_finished>false</tg:version_finished>
            <tg:version_description>common</tg:version_description>
            <tg:version_nett_qty>2000</tg:version_nett_qty>
         </tg:master_version>
         <tg:press_section>
            <tg:signature_id>001</tg:signature_id>
            <tg:sequence_id>0</tg:sequence_id>
            <tg:sequence_alpha>A</tg:sequence_alpha>
            <tg:description>4pp Cover</tg:description>
            <tg:pagination>4</tg:pagination>
            <tg:trim_size>10 x 8</tg:trim_size>
            <tg:version>
               <tg:version_code>COMM</tg:version_code>
               <tg:task_info confirmed="true" maintenance="false" provisional="false">
                  <tg:task_sub_job_id>S019191-1-001COMM</tg:task_sub_job_id>
                  <tg:task_seq_id>0</tg:task_seq_id>
                  <tg:task_description>4pp Cover</tg:task_description>
                  <tg:task_qty_rqd>1500</tg:task_qty_rqd>
                  <tg:task_resource_id>1</tg:task_resource_id>
               </tg:task_info>
            </tg:version>
         </tg:press_section>
         <tg:press_section>
            <tg:signature_id>001</tg:signature_id>
            <tg:sequence_id>1</tg:sequence_id>
            <tg:sequence_alpha>A</tg:sequence_alpha>
            <tg:description>6pp Cover</tg:description>
            <tg:pagination>6</tg:pagination>
            <tg:trim_size>10 x8</tg:trim_size>
            <tg:version>
               <tg:version_code>COMM</tg:version_code>
               <tg:task_info confirmed="true" maintenance="false" provisional="false">
                  <tg:task_sub_job_id>S019191-1-001COMM</tg:task_sub_job_id>
                  <tg:task_seq_id>1</tg:task_seq_id>
                  <tg:task_description>6pp Cover</tg:task_description>
                  <tg:task_qty_rqd>500</tg:task_qty_rqd>
                  <tg:task_resource_id>1</tg:task_resource_id>
               </tg:task_info>
            </tg:version>
         </tg:press_section>
      </tg:order>
</tg:orders>
```

Comment: Can you post a minimal version of your Input XML that illustrates the same issue, and the desired output for that.

Comment: @LingamurthyCS edited the question for you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first point to raise, and you need to remember this, it is an error to have two templates matching the same element, without some sort of extra condition on them. You have two templates matching `order` and two matching `task_info_press_section`. There should only be one of each.

Looking at what you want to achieve, rather than how you are trying to achieve it, I am thinking you should really be taking a different approach. You are trying to add child elements to the `order` element, and you are achieving this by selecting all templates, but with template exceptions to exclude ones which don't match the order number.

The other approach you can take is to explicitly select the child elements you want to copy, based on the order. You can do this fairly easily with keys...

```
<xsl:key name="master_version" match="master_version" use="ORDER" />
<xsl:key name="press_section" match="press_section" use="ORDER" />
<xsl:key name="version" match="version" use="ORDER" />
<xsl:key name="task_info_press_section" match="task_info_press_section" use="ORDER" />
```

So, for the template that matches "order" you would explicitly set the nested "master_version" and "press_section" like so

```
<xsl:template match="order">
   <order job_id="{job_id}" site_code="{site_code}" replace="{Replace}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('master_version', ORDERPK)"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('press_section', ORDERPK)"/>
   </order>
</xsl:template>
```

For the nesting of `task_info_press_section` in `press_section` I would combine it with the template that matches `version`. Then you can more easily add an extra condition to the key that selected the `task_info_press_section`.

```
<xsl:template match="press_section">
  <press_section>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
   <version>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('version', ORDER)/node()"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('task_info_press_section', ORDER)[task_seq_id = current()/sequence_id]"/>
   </version>
  </press_section>
</xsl:template>
```

So `current()` in this case, refers to the current `press_section`

Try this much simplified XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <xsl:key name="master_version" match="master_version" use="ORDER" />
   <xsl:key name="press_section" match="press_section" use="ORDER" />
   <xsl:key name="version" match="version" use="ORDER" />
   <xsl:key name="task_info_press_section" match="task_info_press_section" use="ORDER" />

   <xsl:template match="ORDER"/>
   <xsl:template match="ORDERPK"/>
   <xsl:template match="PRESS_x0020_SECTION"/>
   <xsl:template match="job_id | site_code | replace | Replace"/>
   <xsl:template match="confirmed | maintenance | provisional"/>

   <!-- identity transform -->
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>


       <xsl:template match="dataroot">
     <orders xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" xmlns:tg="http://www.technique-group.com" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.technique-group.com/schemas TGScheduleImport_v1.4.xsd" tg:version="1.2">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="order"/>
     </orders>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="order">
      <order job_id="{job_id}" site_code="{site_code}" replace="{Replace}">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
         <xsl:apply-templates select="key('master_version', ORDERPK)"/>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="key('press_section', ORDERPK)"/>
      </order>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="press_section">
    <press_section>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
       <version>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('version', ORDER)/node()"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('task_info_press_section', ORDER)[task_seq_id = current()/sequence_id]"/>
       </version>
    </press_section>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="task_info_press_section">
    <task_info confirmed="{confirmed}" maintenance="{maintenance}" provisional="{provisional}">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </task_info>
   </xsl:template>
```

Note, in answer to your question about why the `dataroot` is not being removed, it is because you are explicitly copying it to the output

```
<xsl:template match="dataroot">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::*)]|order"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

In the new style sheet, I have effectively combined the templates matching `\` and `dataroot` into one, so `dataroot` is effectively renamed `orders`

```
   <xsl:template match="dataroot">
     <orders xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" xmlns:tg="http://www.technique-group.com" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.technique-group.com/schemas TGScheduleImport_v1.4.xsd" tg:version="1.2">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="order"/>
     </orders>
   </xsl:template>
```

Comment: you are an absolute genius, thank you so much! the only gripe I have is that it is creating copies after the "order" element, but I will try and figure out how to remove them, thank you!

Comment: My apologies. I've made an edit to my answer to fix this. It's just a case of explicitly selecting the "order" element in the template that matches "orders".

Comment: no need to apologize, I'm extremely grateful for the help, thank you very much!